# iText in Javascript - Function is an object

Tags: javascript, pdf, itext, tiff

I am converting a java snippet into JavaScript. Its job is to use itext to convert a tiff into a pdf

```
//http://www.jcgonzalez.com/java-tiff-pdf-example
importPackage(java.io);
importPackage(org.apache.commons.io);
importPackage(com.itextpdf.text.Document);
importPackage(com.itextpdf.text.Image);
importPackage(com.itextpdf.text.Rectangle);
importPackage(com.itextpdf.text.io.FileChannelRandomAccessSource);
importPackage(com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter);
importPackage(com.itextpdf.text.pdf.RandomAccessFileOrArray);
importPackage(com.itextpdf.text.pdf.codec.TiffImage);


function generatePdfFromTiff(sourceFile)  
{
       
       
       var aFile = new RandomAccessFile(sourceFile, "r");
        var inChannel = aFile.getChannel();
        var fcra =  new FileChannelRandomAccessSource();
        
        var document = new Document();
        var baos = new java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream();
        PdfWriter.getInstance(document, baos);
        document.open();              
        var rafa = new RandomAccessFileOrArray(fcra);
        
        var pages = TiffImage.getNumberOfPages(rafa);
        var image;
        for (var i = 1; i <= pages; i++) {            
            image = TiffImage.getTiffImage(rafa, i);
            var pageSize = new Rectangle(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight());
            document.setPageSize(pageSize);
            document.newPage();
            document.add(image);
        }
        document.close();
        aFile.close();       

       return org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.encodeBase64String(baos.toByteArray());
}
```

The challange being that now I keep getting this error

> TypeError: [JavaPackage com.itextpdf.text.io.FileChannelRandomAccessSource] is not a function, it is object.

But I cant understand how it thinks I am using a function